# How to properly implement a tree QAbstractModel with a huge number of nodes?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside

I would like to implement a model with tree structure. I am using python, but I guess the same problem occurs in C++.

As I can read in the documentation and on some forum posts (e.g. https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/10735-deleting-internal-pointer-in-QModelIndex), `QModelIndex` has been designed to be fast, with copy-construction being basically only copying its fields. This means, there is absolutely no way of knowing when a given model index will be thrown away (in the sense no more views use it), even though the documentation ask the view not to store these model indexes...

In python, the problem is that it's not possible for pyside/pyqt to use ref count on whatever is passed as `internalPointer` : https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-bz-archive/618.html

In C++, The problem is it's not possible to use smart pointer nor knowing when to safely delete this internal pointer

Given that, I am wondering how would one implement a tree model with data loaded dynamically, and with potentially a huge amount of data (e.g. Even if it's not my current application, imagine some infinite model that would fetch a web page, and build a tree of all linked web page accessed from it...).

I imagine, the memory required just for storing traversal informations would grow to an amount I would call it "memory leak"... Plus you need a container to store all traversal info you create to delete them at the model destruction...

My first question : Is this assumption true (should I worry about the growth of traversal information) ?

Second question : If I have reasons to worry, how to properly deal with it ? (how to know when I can free these)

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I think an index is only a location descriptor for the data. So the index must not have a pointer to the real data, but you can load the data on access.

Comment: Why don't you just create a simple read-only model and profile it to see what happens? SO is not the place to ask open-ended, hypothetical questions. Please provide an [mre] that demonstrates a specific problem.

Comment: @gerum yes it is, but or trees, you still need to store some traversal information (parent for example), and the way you that information may need to be more than just an id. And even though you can use a map/dict to link the id to this information, this map/dict growth with the same complexity as the number of items (only one depth level less)

Comment: @ekhumoro this is not about "what is the best way ?", this is about "what is a way ?".
a mwe is not relevant here since it's a general question that is pertinent for python and c++. Please provide me a better SE site if you still think this question has not its place here...

Comment: I said nothing about "what is the best way". You have provided no evidence whatsoever that there is an actual problem, but instead have given only your assumptions and "worries". All you need to do is create a simple test-case (i.e. like the [Simple Tree Model Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)) that shows a *specific, measurable problem* that others can then try to reproduce.

Comment: PS: you could also look at the source code of the [QFileSystemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) for inspiration, since that provides a fully working example of what you seem to be asking about (i.e. a potentially unbounded hierarchical model).

Comment: I already checked out the QFileSystemModel source, no delete seems to be perform on nodes except when a file is removed

Comment: So are you claiming that `QFileSystemModel` has some kind of memory leak? What *actual problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: I would indeed claim so... If the user gets fun to open each folders one by one, I don't see how the private file system nodes could be freed...

Comment: @hl037_ Your question seems the premise to a premature optimization and unnecessary speculation. *If* and *when* you will actually need to face such a situation, then consider what could cause the problem and find solution to prevent that: for instance, a system that keeps track of previously expanded parent items that "expire" (and become collapsed if they are not yet) after a certain number of *other* siblings of those parent items are expanded, and then call a function on the model that destroys the child nodes to release resources.

Answer (score 1):

A basic structure may be (similar to the `QFileSystemModel`)

```
struct TreeItem
{
    ~TreeItem() {qDeleteAll(children);}

    TreeItem *parent;
    QVector<TreeItem*> children;  

    // your actual data
    QString url; // f.ex. the url of the link.
    ...
}

class MyTree
{
public:
    TreeItem root;
}
```

As `internalPointer`, you can store a pointer to the actual `TreeItem`.

Note that this pattern does not contain a memory leak, as everything is correctly destructed when `MyTree` is destructed. It is indeed the case that no memory is released until `MyTree` itself is destructed. By filling TreeItem::children on the fly (i.e. only when needed), this structure can represent an infinite tree.

If memory usage is a concern, you should keep the footprint of the data stored in `TreeItem` to a bare minimum, f.ex. only the url and not the content or other metadata of that page.

Another approach may be to store the tree structure in a (temporary) database and use the row index of the database as the `internalPointer`.

Note that you shouldn't exaggerate the impact of an infinite tree (as long as you only create the needed items), but this depends of course on your use case. A human will probably never open the tree to a depth further than 5 to 10 (and even if he does so, he will probably open only a single branch to this depth).